# Recursion of Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, linked-list

When given an array of integers, I'm trying to change each element with the product of the integers before it.

For example, `int[] array = {2,2,3,4};` is now: `{2, 4, 12, 48};`

I added each element to a `LinkedList`, and I'm trying to do this recursively.

This is what I have:

```
Node curr = list.getFirst();
product(curr);

public static void product(Node curr)
{
    if(curr == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int data = curr.getData() * curr.getNext().getData();
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        curr.setNext(newNode);

        //  product(curr);
    }
}
```

The first product works: {2,4}, but when I try to put in the recursion, I get a stackoverflow. Any suggestions??

Edit: So the reason that I'm either getting a **stackoverflow** or **null pointer exception** is because I'm updating the list, and then trying to get the next integer(but since there's only two elements in the list, there isn't a `getNext()`). I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Part of the problem would seem to be that your adding a next node, so everytime you recurse there is a next node, hence no end to the recursion. Not sure why Tims solution didnt fix that though.

Comment: @BenKnoble I accidentally left in one line from his old program in my original post, though I have since removed it.  Maybe he ran this older version of the code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is very possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were getting a bit tied up in the recursion.  I modified your method to accept a `Node` along with the product from the previous iteration.  At each step of the iteration I update the value in the already-existing `List`, so there is no need for using the `new` operator.

```
public static void product(Node curr, int value) {
    if (curr == null) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int data = value * curr.getData();  // compute current product
        curr.setData(data);                 // update Node
        product(curr.getNext(), data);      // make recursive call
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `newNode` from?

Comment: Sorry I am on a mobile device and I forgot to delete his old code.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Although I'm still getting a stack overflow with this code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error?  The code should work with no issues.

Comment: I wanted to do it with the setData method, but your way worked!

Comment: So just wondering, would it be possible to do it without setData() ?

Comment: Well the call I make to `setData()` is only to update the value of the current `Node` in the recursion.  If you can make this update some other way, then yes, you can do it without `setData()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you call recursive method on the current node, so it is actually never move forward in the LinkedList. You can simply update the next node's data and call the recursive method on it. See the code below:

```
Node curr = list.getFirst();
product(curr);

public static void product(Node curr)
{
    Node next  = curr.getNext();   
    if(next == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int data = curr.getData() * next.getData();
        next.setData(data);
        product(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a null pointer exception, I think because we don't know if curr has a getNext, this may be why my original code didnt work eithe r

Comment: Yes, you are right, next can be null so we should return when next is null. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two issues with the code.

> 1. The recursion never ends, i.e. it is not actually moving to a smaller "subproblem" as the recursion is calling the same node again
>      and again.
> 2. After creating a new node and modifying the next we also need to connect the node "after" the next node otherwise the link will be
>      lost.  Please check the below method which addresses both the issues.

Although I didn't do an excessive testing it is working for simple dataset.
Original List: 
2->4->5->6->8->null
Multiplied List:
2->8->40->240->1920->null

```
public void product(Node curr) {
    if (curr.getNext() == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        int data = curr.getData() * curr.getNext().getData();
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setData(data);
        Node nodeAfterNextNode = curr.getNext().getNext();
        newNode.setNext(nodeAfterNextNode);
        curr.setNext(newNode);

        product(newNode);
    }
}
```